# Preferences & javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, aes, preferences

I've been staring at this code for hours, and I must be missing something silly. As a result someone's help here is greatly appreciated.

Below is example code, the simplest I could get it to repro this issue. The code works fine the first time it runs, but then after the preference has been created for the IV, it fails then after.

My real code has much more stored in preferences than this one, I simplified it a lot in troubleh shooting to make it easier to isolate.

My goal is to create a class that allows me to store preferences encrypted with AES 128 encryption with a key derived from a user-supplied password. e.g. Secure preferences. I took out all the user-supplied pwd stuff in troubleshooting.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Settings {
    private Preferences prefs = null;
    private byte[] iv = null;
    private SecretKey secret = null;
    Cipher cipher = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Settings t = new Settings();
       String encText = t.encryptText("HELLO");//Encrypt a value
       String output = t.decryptText(encText);//Decrypt the value
       System.out.println(output); //Display the decrypted value.
    }

    public Settings(){
        try {
            String parentClass = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();//Really only controls where the prefs go, shouldn't matter.
            this.prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Class.forName(parentClass));
            Random r = new SecureRandom();
            KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGen.init(128); // 128 bit key
            this.secret = keyGen.generateKey();

            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
        private String encryptText(String plainText){
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secret);
            AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

            this.iv = prefs.getByteArray("IV", null);
            if(this.iv == null){
                this.iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
                prefs.putByteArray("IV", this.iv);
            }
            byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String ret = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(ciphertext));
            return ret;
        } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException | InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "";
   }
    private String decryptText(String cipherText){
        try {
            this.iv = prefs.getByteArray("IV", null);
            byte[] cText = Base64.decodeBase64(cipherText); 
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.secret, new IvParameterSpec(this.iv));
            String ret = new String(cipher.doFinal(cText), "UTF-8");
            return ret;
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "";
   }
}
```

Stacktrace that is only received on 2+ runs:

```
Feb 07, 2015 9:02:46 PM com.test.Settings decryptText

SEVERE: null
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at com.test.Settings.decryptText(Settings.java:77)
    at com.test.Settings.main(Settings.java:34)
```

------------  EDIT Correct Answer ------------
As GregS pointed out, I didn't load the IV into the encrypt routine when the preference existed, as a result there was a mismatch. Below is the updated encrypt function which the problem fixed.

```
    private String encryptText(String plainText){
        try {
            this.iv = prefs.getByteArray("IV", null);
            if(this.iv == null) { //If not set, set the IV
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secret);
                AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
                this.iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
                prefs.putByteArray("IV", this.iv);
            } else {
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secret, new IvParameterSpec(this.iv));
            }

            byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String ret = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(ciphertext));
            return ret;
        } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException | InvalidKeyException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Settings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "";
   }
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the IV parameter for decryption (and completely remove the IV handling)? This will use the default IV for both encryption and decryption. Maybe the problem is that the Preferences are not empty.

Comment: As @ArtjomB. notes, if the preferences are not empty in `encryptText` then you end up retrieving an iv from the preferences but never setting the iv in the cipher instance. However, in `decryptText` you do set the iv in the cipher instance. As a result, the encrypt side uses a default IV (probably all zeros) while the decrypt side uses the IV obtained from the preferences.

Comment: GregS, you are absolutely correct. If the pref isn't set, the IV is used, but if the IV isn't set, I never loaded that to be used. That is exactly my problem.

Now that you point it out, it seems obvious, but I stared at that code for hours. Thank-you for your help!

If you want to post that answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Doug I'm glad you fixed your problem. However, please don't add a solution into your own question text. Please post your own answer.

Comment: @Duncan I was giving GregS an opportunity to post the answer, since he gave me the answer in a comment. If he doesn't post in the next day, I'll post the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GregS pointed out, I didn't load the IV into the encrypt routine when the preference existed, as a result there was a mismatch. Below is the updated encrypt function which the problem fixed.

```
private String encryptText(String plainText){
    try {
        this.iv = prefs.getByteArray("IV", null);
        if(this.iv == null) { //If not set, set the IV
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secret);
            AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
            this.iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
            prefs.putByteArray("IV", this.iv);
        } else {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secret, new IvParameterSpec(this.iv));
        }

        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String ret = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(ciphertext));
        return ret;
    } catch (InvalidParameterSpecException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException | InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Settings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return "";
   }
```